# zero_copy with dynamic size account in Anchor?

Tags: anchor

I'm wondering how to properly integrate a type of account, whose size differ from account to account, with anchor?

For example, the data in this type of account (say `MyAccount`) is organized as following: First, a `u32` integer called `a`. Second, another `u32` integer called `b`. Third, some bytes with length `a + b`. In this way, the size of this account is `4 + 4 + a + b`.

Besides, `a + b` could be very large (e.g., over 10KB), so I don't want to use `Account<'info, MyAccount>` because this will deserialize the whole account. I want the zero copy feature. However, I can't simply add `#[account(zero_copy)]` to `MyAccount`, because the `ZeroCopy` trait requires `MyAccount` to be `Sized` and `Pod`.

For now, I've found a workaround like this:

```
#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct MyAccount {
    x: u32,
    y: u32,
    data: [u8; 0],
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Update<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub existing_account: AccountLoader<'info, MyAccount>,
}

#[program]
pub mod example {
    use core::slice;
    use std::mem;
    use super::*;

    pub fn update(ctx: Context<Update>, index: u16, input: u8) -> Result<()> {
        // Load the account to be updated
        let my_account = &mut ctx.accounts.existing_account.load_mut()?;

        // Update the data at the specified index
        let index = index as usize;
        let data: &mut [u8] = unsafe {
            let p: *mut u8 = mem::transmute(&mut my_account.data);
            slice::from_raw_parts_mut(p, (my_account.x + my_account.y) as usize)
        };
        data[index] = input;

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

In this way, I can fulfill my requirements. However, the generated IDL is not correct. In the IDL, it says the `data` field is an array of length 0... I'm wondering if there's any other more elegant way to fulfill my requirements?

---

(Edit) My use case: the size of `MyAccount` won't change once initializing/creating the account. Though its content could change, its size will never change. This case is very common. For example, in a multiplayer PVP game, the number of players won't change during a game, but the players' states could change (e.g., deal damage to decrease enemy player's HP).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using zero-copy the struct has to be a fixed size. Your options are:

1. Figure out what the largest data you intend to store is, use that as the size of your byte slice, knowing that the unused portion will be zeroed (you might store the length of the valid section to load the actual blob more easily). This obviously wastes space due to the zeroed portion. For example `data: [u8; 1024],`, if you then write 24 bytes to this slice, 1000 bytes are zeroed/wasted until future use.
2. Don't use zero-copy, this limits your memory allowance significantly.
3. Have several similar fixed-size structs with different size levels to avoid wasting space. Internally, load them as bytes and bytemuck the smaller structs into the larger one (with padding) when handling them internally so you can treat them all as the "same".

Comment: Thanks for answering!! Regarding you point 2, I think not using zero-copy not only limits the memory allowance, but also has the same issue with point 1, am I correct? i.e., the size of an account is still fixed and denotes the maximum possible size one account could use. Other zeroed, unused bytes are also wasted.

Comment: Regarding your point 3, **firstly**, you say it can "avoid wasting space". Do you mean it can "waste less space"? Since there can be only a few fixed-size structs, while my account could be any size (thus having several thousands variants, from 0 Byte to several KB). **Secondly**, with your approach, do I have to write an extremely large `match`-expression to check which fixed-size struct I should "bytemuck" into? Seems really annoying, or I misunderstand something? (To be continued in the following comment)

Comment: **Thirdly**, with `bytemuck` crate, I can only "bytemuck" a bunch of bytes to a struct with same size. However, with my workaround described in the question, I can know the size of the bunch of bytes at runtime. Then I can `mem::transmute` the bytes into a `*mut u8`/`*const u8`, and create the data slice with `slice::from_raw_parts_mut`/`slice::from_raw_parts`. This workaround doesn't require developers to specify the size of structs at compile time. Doesn't this workaround seem nicer? In my use case, the account size won't change once initializing/creating. Updated my use case to the question

Comment: With a regular non-zero-copy account you could use a Vec and size dynamically. Re: point 3, yes, you could pick a few fixed sizes that would waste less space in common use-cases. If your byte data is truly arbitrary then it likely doesn't apply. I think your idea to transmute probably makes sense, but I try to avoid it because transmute is a real footgun if you use it wrong. If a mutable ref to the slice works for you I think you have a few possibilities. You can always borrow data from the slice directly like `&ctx.accounts.some_acc.try_borrow_mut_data()?[8..]` and manipulate it as needed.

Comment: With a regular non-zero-copy account, you said I could use a `Vec` and size dynamically. I suppose by "dynamically", you mean the size of  the **deserialized struct** is dynamic in runtime memory. While the account size is still fixed and is the maximum possible size (which is specified by us at compile time) of this type I suppose?

Comment: If you have an account that's not zero copy and contains just `data: Vec<u8>` and the Vec is empty, iirc it will consume 24 bytes on-chain for the Vec pointers and that's it. If it has 8 items, then 32 bytes, etc. But, you can't dynamically resize these accounts without some extra work, so once you init the account with data the Vec can't grow, i.e. another ix can't append to it. For this reason some people will pad the Vec with data to leave some space. There's also a cap around 32kB. Imo dealing with Vec on-chain is a headache.

Comment: Just done an experiment ([here](https://beta.solpg.io/65f110f4cffcf4b13384cfac) is the Solana playground share link), and the conclusion is: `Vec` does NOT consume 24 bytes on-chain. I understand it takes 24 bytes in memory (8 bytes for each of pointing address, current length, current capacity), but after `AnchorDeserialize`, it only takes 4 bytes on-chain (denoting length). Anchor doc also describes this behavior [here](https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/space). Besides the doc also says that *"Account size is fixed so account should be initialized with sufficient space from the beginning"*.

Comment: Yes my mistake, there's no reason to store the pointers on chain as they are irrelevant until runtime, so only the length is needed for a blank Vec. Same principle though, you would need 8 bytes for a blank Vec but it wouldn't be able to grow beyond that.